# Меню с иконками пунктов в html и меню с иконками как background в css

Tags: html, css

Помогите, пожалуйста, подредактировать менюшку.

Сначала вставляла изображения в тегах, но `border` никак не смогла выровнять на уровне текста и картинку так же рядом:

```css
ul li{
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #464646;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.top_header{
  height: 39px;
}
.top_header li{
  padding-top: 7px;
  height: 32px;
}
.top_header img{
  margin: 0 6px;
}
.menu li a{
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  height: 18px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 41px;
}
.menu li:hover{
  background: #8ea4ca;
}
.menu li:hover a{
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.menu li:last-child a{
  color: #eb1f27;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_header">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/phone-book.png" alt=""/></span>Контакты</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/shopping-bag.png" alt=""/></span>Заказ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/wallet.png" alt=""/></span>Оплата</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/pie-chart.png" alt=""/></span>Рассрочка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/delivery-truck.png" alt=""/></span>Доставка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/certifikate.png" alt=""/></span>Гарантия</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/ikonka-form.png" alt=""/></span>Отзывы</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/sitemap.png" alt=""/></span>Карта сайта</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/3-circles-inside-the-dialogue-box.png" alt=""/></span>Блог</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/gift-box.png" alt=""/></span>Акции</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Потом поняла, что надо делать как `background` иконки, потому что позже при наведении должны будут меняться на другие, но все равно криво.
Как лучше сделать?

```css
ul li{
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #464646;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.top_header{
  height: 39px;
}
.top_header li{
  padding-top: 7px;
  height: 32px;
}
.menu li a{
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0px 10px 0 20px;
  height: 18px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 41px;
}
.menu li:hover{
  background: #8ea4ca;
}
.menu li:hover a{
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.menu li:last-child a{
  color: #eb1f27;
}

.menu li:nth-child(1) a{
  background: url(http://www.images-store.ru/townwars_images/i/clan/icon_29.png) 5px no-repeat;
}
.menu li:nth-child(2) a{
  background: url(http://www.images-store.ru/townwars_images/i/clan/icon_29.png) 5px no-repeat;
}
.menu li:nth-child(3) a{
  background: url(http://www.images-store.ru/townwars_images/i/clan/icon_29.png) 5px no-repeat;
}
.menu li:nth-child(4) a{
  background: url(http://www.images-store.ru/townwars_images/i/clan/icon_29.png) 5px no-repeat;
}
.menu li:nth-child(5) a{
  background: url(http://www.images-store.ru/townwars_images/i/clan/icon_29.png) 5px no-repeat;
}
.menu li:nth-child(6) a{
  background: url(http://www.images-store.ru/townwars_images/i/clan/icon_29.png) 5px no-repeat;
}
.menu li:nth-child(7) a{
  background: url(http://www.images-store.ru/townwars_images/i/clan/icon_29.png) 5px no-repeat;
}
.menu li:nth-child(8) a{
  background: url(http://www.images-store.ru/townwars_images/i/clan/icon_29.png) 5px no-repeat;
}
.menu li:nth-child(9) a{
  background: url(http://www.images-store.ru/townwars_images/i/clan/icon_29.png) 5px no-repeat;
}
.menu li:nth-child(10) a{
  background: url(http://www.images-store.ru/townwars_images/i/clan/icon_29.png) 5px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_header">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#"><span>Контакты</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Заказ</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Оплата</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Рассрочка</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Доставка</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Гарантия</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Отзывы</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Карта сайта</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Блог</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Акции</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Тк по моими попыткам не особо ясно что хочу сделать, вот картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.menu li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu a {
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #464646;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 12px 10px 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.menu a:before {
  background: #ccc;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 10px;
  width: 1px;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background: #8ea4ca;
}

.menu li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu li:hover a:before {
  background: transparent;
}

.menu li:last-child a {
  color: #eb1f27;
}

.menu li:nth-child(1) a { background-image: url(http://www.images-store.ru/townwars_images/i/clan/icon_29.png); }
.menu li:nth-child(2) a { background-image: url(http://www.images-store.ru/townwars_images/i/clan/icon_29.png); }
.menu li:nth-child(3) a { background-image: url(http://www.images-store.ru/townwars_images/i/clan/icon_29.png); }
.menu li:nth-child(4) a { background-image: url(http://www.images-store.ru/townwars_images/i/clan/icon_29.png); }
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Заказ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Оплата</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Рассрочка</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```